# Dirty read in Oracle - how to read uncommitted record

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

In SQL Server, let's say I am testing a functionality, I can apply a breakpoint in app and check the uncommitted records in DB like this:

```
select * from mytable with(nolock)
```

Is there an equivalent dirty read available in Oracle., As far as I can see, I am unable to find such a feature.

[Here it says it's not possible](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#CNCPT1322) at all. From debugging a core issue perspective, is there some way to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not convinced that reading uncommitted records from another session is a core feature of a database. Why don't you just do a `SELECT * FROM mytable` from your own (debugging) session? Or do you have intermediate commits (which is a bad idea IMHO) and try to debug around them with your breakpoints?

Comment: You have a point Frank., I am fixing my issues by executing queries from the same session in the code., When I was using SQL Server, I never had a need for this, since it was allowing dirty read. Just curious why oracle doesn't support such an alternative

Comment: I recommend reading what Tom Kyte has to say about this - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html and https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1729145331430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do dirty reads in Oracle. 
For debugging, i think you can :

Add a table in your code and store the intermediate data in that table. You can verifty this data post run. Also, thibk it will be better to make the insert in this table an autonomous transaction.

Hope it helps

Vishad